# IOS: read txt file when I launch an app

Tags: ios, xcode, text-files

Everytime I launch an app, I should to read 5 txt file where are stored some information; then the methods that read and stored data in array from these file should be write in my firstview controller (class of my first view) or in class appdelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the relevant view controller (probably viewDidLoad).

It would look something like this (untested):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *fileNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fileName1.txt", @"fileName2.txt", @"etc", nil];
    NSMutableArray *fileStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<[fileNames count]; i++) {
        NSString *aFileName = [fileNames objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *aFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aFileName];
        NSString *aFileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aFilePath];
        [fileStrings addObject:aFileContents];
        [aFileContents release];
    }
    myStrings = fileStrings; // Some array to store to
}
```

Comment: I know the code, but is it better to do in relevant view controller or in appdelegate class? what's the difference?

Comment: Do it in the view controller... there should be no issue with that

Comment: @AlexCoplan Can you elaborate on `pathForResource:aFileName`, in an iOS iPhone app, does that default to some standard directory for the app?

Comment: @SAFX when you're calling it on the bundle, it looks for any files you've added to your application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is configuration info that you are reading. I would suggest using a [**pList**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html) instead of using text files.

Apple has really optimized reading from & to a plist. Hope this helps...